# compare xml files using python

Tags: python, xml, xmldiff

I want to compare these two xml files:

File1.xml:

```
<ngs_sample id="40332">
  <workflow value="salmonella" version="101_provisional" />
  <results>
  <gastro_prelim_st reason="not novel" success="false">
      <type st="1364" />
      <type st="9999" />
  </gastro_prelim_st>
 </results>
</ngs_sample>
```

File2.xml:

```
<ngs_sample id="40332">
  <workflow value="salmonella" version="101_provisional" />
  <results>
  <gastro_prelim_st reason="not novel" success="false">
      <type st="1364" />
   </gastro_prelim_st>
 </results>
</ngs_sample>
```

I've used `xmldiff` to compare a.xml with b.xml:

```
def compare_xmls(observed,expected):

    from xmldiff import main, formatting
    formatter = formatting.DiffFormatter()
    diff = main.diff_files(observed,expected,formatter=formatter)
    return diff

out = compare_xmls(a.xml, b.xml)
print(out)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[delete, /ngs_sample/results/gastro_prelim_st/type[2]]
```

Anyone know how to identify what is the difference between the two xml files, i.e. what has been deleted compared to the file b.xml. Anyone recommend any other way of comparing xml files in python?

Comment: For comparing differences in general I use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), so if you don't *need* to do it in python, it's a pretty handy tool.  But if you must, it seems the output already tells you the difference exactly? (That the second `type` tag under `ngs_sample/...prelim_st/` was deleted).  Did you mean you wanted to see the values being deleted?

Comment: Yes I want to see what has been deleted, i.e. what is the difference between the two xmls.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from the output that's missing then? It's already telling you that second `type` tag has been deleted.  As it stands it's not clear, would be helpful if you stated your expected output instead.

Comment: Helpful to say <type st="9999" /> is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch to the `XMLFormatter` and manually filter out the results:

```
...
# Change formatter:
formatter = formatting.XMLFormatter(normalize=formatting.WS_BOTH)

...

# after `out` has been retrieved:
import re
for i in out.splitlines():
  if re.search(r'\bdiff:\w+', i):
    print(i)

# Result:
#       <type st="9999" diff:delete=""/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [xmldiff](https://xmldiff.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) to perform this exact task.

### main.py

```
from xmldiff import main
diff = main.diff_files("file1.xml", "file2.xml")
print(diff)
```

### output

```
[DeleteNode(node='/ngs_sample/results/gastro_prelim_st/type[2]')]
```

Comment: Not sure if you read the question but this doesnt answer my query

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use `xml2` https://github.com/clone/xml2 (and something like `bash` process substitution)

`$ diff --color <(xml2 < File1.xml) <(xml2 < File2.xml)`

```
7,8d6
< /ngs_sample/results/gastro_prelim_st/type
< /ngs_sample/results/gastro_prelim_st/type/@st=9999
```